# Why are the integral form of the GR equations problematic?

Tags: general-relativity, causality, greens-functions

I have heard that working with the integral form of the GR equations is problematic - relative to determining a Greens function.

Can someone explain the details as why?

Comment: Can you point to where you saw this claim?

Comment: It was a comment I received through a personal communication and a well informed source.

Comment: Can you please put the "integral form of the GR equations" in your post?

Comment: Are you thinking of the order reduction of the Landau-Lifshitz formulation of Einstein's equations?

Comment: Because it's non-linear?

Comment: @Slereah and you are saying the differential form is linear? Or at least less non-linear?